# NHibernate eager load with FetchMany for subclass only

Tags: nhibernate, subclass, eager-loading

I have a following (simplified) hierarchy:

```
class Account
{
    AccountType Type;
    long Id;
    string Name;
}

public enum AccountType
{
    UsualAccount = 0,
    SpecialAccount = 1
}

class SpecialAccount : Account 
{
    List<SpecialItem> SpecialItems;
}

class SpecialItem
{
    long Id;
    string Name;
}
```

To help NHibernate to detect subclass SpecialItem, I use the following code in the Account mapping:

```
<discriminator column="Type" formula="Type"/>
```

and SpecialItems have lazy="false" set in the mapping, but as far as I know, it is ignored during LINQ queries.

Now when I use LINQ and call

```
Session.Query<Account>().ToList();
```

I see that SpecialItems are fetched in a separate query. I would like to load them eagerly.

I could do that using

```
Session.Query<Account>().FetchMany(a => a.SpecialItems).ToList();
```

but there is a problem - SpecialItems is the property of the SpecialAccount. So I somehow need FetchMany to work only if a is a SpecialAccount class.

I tried even something as ugly as:

```
Session.Query<Account>().
    FetchMany(a => (a is SpecialAccount ? (a as SpecialAccount ).SpecialItems : null));
```

but NHibernate still selected SpecialItems in a separate query.

**How can I make NHibernate select SpecialItems for SpecialAccount in a single query?**

Additional information

I am using MS SQL Express 2012 and NHibernate configuration has the following lines:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
<property name="adonet.batch_size">50</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
```

NHibernate.dll version 3.2.0.4000

Here are the queries generated by NHibernate for one existing SpecialAccount with Id=2, as they appear in MS SQL Profiler (with selected events RPCCompleted, Exec Prepared SQL, SQL:StmtCompleted):

```
select account0_.Id as Id5_, account0_.Type as Type5_, account0_.Name as Name5_, account0_.Type as clazz_ from tAccount account0_ 

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT specialite0_.AccountId as Id1_, specialite0_.Id as specialite1_1_, specialite0_.Id as specialite1_13_0_, specialite0_.Name as Name13_0_ 
FROM tSpecialItem specialite0_ WHERE specialite0_.Id=@p0',N'@p0 bigint',@p0=2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't to a "conditional fetch". You need at least two queries.

You can, however, group them using a **Future** LINQ query, so it would be effectively one roundtrip:

```
session.Query<SpecialAccount>().FetchMany(x => x.SpecialItems).ToFuture();
var accounts = session.Query<Account>().ToFuture();
```

Both queries run when you enumerate `accounts`. We don't store the results of the first query *explicitly*, but the `SpecialAccounts` are loaded in memory with their corresponding `SpecialItems` collections, so there are no extra DB calls.

Comment: Thanks, ToFuture seems a good idea, but for some reason it did not change the SQL generated. Profiler still shows two "exec sp_executesql" queries. Maybe ToFuture does not work with Fetch as expected (as they say here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143480/good-behaviour-for-eager-loading-multiple-siblings-and-grandchildren-cousins )...

Comment: It WorksOnMyMachine™, using NH 3.3.1 and SQL2008. Just one query sent to the DB (and it doesn't have sp_executesql). Wanna post your profiler output as an edit to your question?

Comment: Added more information about my configuration and the queries in the SQL Profiler.

Comment: The queries you are using are different from the ones I provided. Could you please post your queries, besides the resulting SQL?

Comment: Actually my classes have some more fields (just simple CLR types) in them, so I cleaned up the queries to keep the bare minimum. I tried the LINQ code almost exactly as you posted and added accounts.ToList() to trigger the SQL, but still I see two queries in the Profiler. I guess, I'll have to create a completely clean project from scratch to match my simplified example, so I can see better what might be different.